# how to Predict dice throws mathematically?

Tags: probability

I used to play a dice game at the local club .Its a very simple game , where there will be 6 colors ( lets call it numbers from 1-6 just for the sake ) .There will be 3 six sided die and each face of the die will be having one those six colors , such that all the six faces covers all six colors. The bettings will be placed on any one of the colors or any number of colors we want. Such three dice will be rolled , if any one of those dice faces up with the color that i've made the bet , i'll get paid 1:1 , if two dice shows up the same color 1:2  and if all three dice shows up with same color i'll get paid 1:10. Finally if no dice shows up i'l lose my money .Pls help me how to predict the color (or number) for 3 dice rolls for throwing sevel times . Pls help me im losing lot of money on this .

Comment: By definition, you can't predict dice rolls...

Comment: You can't predict any of that. The best you could do is to calculate the probability of having 1/2/3 colours right. But before you do that: if you are losing (lots of) money, stop gambling.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck-a-luck

Comment: Never gamble thinking some easy computation will give you an edge!  The House has always worked out the math carefully and optimal play at your end will result in steady losses.  That's just how it works.

Comment: According to the wikipedia article cited by @Henry, you're going to lose 4.6% of your money, in the long run, and there's absolutely nothing you can do about this. If you bet small, and you're having fun, maybe that's OK. If not, stop betting.

Comment: @lulu. I was wondering why the two numbers don't agree. The 4.6% number seems to be for odds of 1:1, 2:1, 10:1. What am I missing ??

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics can't predict how the dice will land, but it can predict how much money you'll lose. It looks [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck-a-luck) describes the game you're playing.  It says that you'll lose 4.6% of the money you bet, in the long run. Of course, there will be nights when you win, and nights when you lose far more than 4.6%. Mathematics can predict the probability of losing 20% of your money on a given night when you play 100 rounds of the game, for example.

If you bet small, and you're having fun, maybe it's OK to lose 4.6% of your money. If not, stop betting.